# Better way to test triggering of email functionality

Tags: asp.net, email, testing

In e-commerce industry we are using **asp .net technology** in the application. In that **email must trigger from ie.. day 1 ,3,5,7,11,21,.. 100 days** after **new user registration**.

How can I test whether email functionality is working in proper way or not.

Comment: Without code it's impossible to narrow down an answer to something practical.  Usually you'd isolate the various bits of logic and test them.  At a larger level, you could manipulate the database to modify user registration date/times and then trigger the email checking process.  However this might not be practical.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code such way that it triggers after minute 1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 21...100. If it works then you can be sure that it will work for days as well.
What would be a reason of working for minutes, but working for days? The difference is, probably, in a single line of code.

After such testing you can easily launch your application \ service in production and register yourself first, in 5-10 days before the launch. Then, if even something will not work (for example, on day 21 the message won't be sent), you will have enough time to look through the logs and fix the problem before other people could know about its existence.

As for me, I would unsubscribe from a service which tells me that I have registered N days ago.